# Undo, Redo is jumping around and unpredictable (Test on PHPStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStrom v 8.0.2
While i was hit command-Z to undo thing.
The editor jump around to somewhere but not to the cursor as illustrated image.
That makes me very annoyed.

[image]

Is this a bug or have i setting something wrong?

### HERE IS HOW TO REPRODUCE

1. Edit any line
2. Place the cursor far... far away from the edit line
3. Hit command-Z to UNDO thing <-- The editor will jump to the edited line
4. Hit command-shift-Z to REDO thing, the editor jump back to the line in (2) <--- NO... IT SHOULD NOT

Seem like Jetbrains does fix this in PHPStorm v9 EAP.
But that program will expired after 30 days, Any where to implement this in PHPStorm v8.0.3 please?

One more thing, I can't find any keyboard shortcut key for auto indent for the whole document, please advise.

Best Regards,

Comment: 1) Use latest version -- 8.0.3; If you want -- you may try v9 EAP build; 2) It "jumps" fine for me -- so .. no clue here; 3) `Code | Auto-Indent Lines...`

Comment: ctrl-alt-L formats the entire document (including indents)

Comment: Sorry, 8.0.3 still produce the problem.

Comment: bro update to new version. Im using 8.0.3. its Perfect

Comment: What "undo" does can depend on the window that's in focus. For example, if the editor is in focus, you will undo edits; if the Projects window is in focus, you might be undoing a "new file" or "rename file" action. Perhaps the window you want to apply the undo is not in focus.

Comment: @kuporific, i did focus on the right window. But the jumpping behavior is still not unexpected.
I'm found how to reproduce, please check in my edit.
It does fix in v9 but still looking for the way to implement this in v8.0.3

Comment: *"Seem like Jetbrains does fix this in PHPStorm v9 EAP. But that program will expired after 30 days"* Every EAP build (for major versions) comes with its own 30 days license. New builds appear every 2 weeks or so -- before the license gets expired.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Intellij default behavior; it treats `cursor movements` as `edit actions` and as such they are being undone and redone.

See [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206082869-Undo-and-cursor-position)